# Does the System F with pairs have the strong normalisation and subject reduction properties?

Tags: reference-request, lo.logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus, polymorphism

It is easy to look in a lot of textbooks the proofs of subject reduction and strong normalisation for System F, also, sometimes there are definitions of System F with pairs, where (t,r) is a term, not only an encoding. The question is, what would be the reference for this system?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The treatment of pairs given by encoding, such as that in *Proofs and Types*, isn't what you usually want since they aren't "surjective pairs", i.e., there is no eta rule.  Let's call surjective pairs, products.

An extension of system F with products and unit is given in: Di Cosmo, 1995,  *Isomorphisms of types: from lambda-calculus to information retrieval and language design*,  Birkhauser: Basel.

Answer (score 6):

You can add arbitrary (positive) inductive types to system F, and show that the system with appropriate eliminators is SN. This is treated in Mendler's thesis [here](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/info/Projects/Nuprl/documents/Mendler/InductiveDefinition.html).

Comment: This is also treated, albeit in somewhat sketchy detail, in sections 11.4 and 11.5 of *[Proofs and Types](http://www.paultaylor.eu/stable/Proofs+Types.html)*.